# Expected maximum of absolute centered iid RV

Tags: order-statistics

Assume a set of random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ which are i.i.d. according to some unknown distribution $D$. All we know is $var(X_i)=\sigma^2$, and $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$. What, if anything, can we say about $\sup_i \vert X_i\vert$, e.g. bounds on its expectation etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Let $ES$ be the expected supremum $E[\sup_i |X_i|]$.

**ES has no lower bound:**

There is no positive lower bound on $ES$. Suppose
\begin{align}
P[X=-\sigma/\sqrt{t}] &= \ \ t/2\\
P[X=\ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ ] &=1-t \\
P[X=+\sigma/\sqrt{t}] &= \ \ t/2\\
\end{align}
Then
$$ES=\sigma\,\frac{1-(1-t)^n}{\sqrt{t}}$$
By choosing $t$ sufficiently close to $0$, we can make $ES$ arbitrarily small.

**ES has an upper bound near $\sigma\sqrt{n/2}$**:

If $|X|$ has a quantile function of $Q(p)$, then
$$ES = \int_0^1 np^{n-1}Q(p)\,dp$$

So by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{align}
ES^2 &\le \int_0^1 (np^{n-1})^2\,dp \int_0^1 Q^2(p)\,dp\\
ES^2 &\le \frac{n^2}{2n-1} \sigma^2\\
ES &\le\sigma\sqrt{\frac{n^\phantom{;}}{2-\frac1n}}
\end{align}
Furthermore this bound is achieved when $X$ is symmetric about 0 and $|X|$ has a quantile function proportional to $Q(p)=p^{n-1}$.